# last input not working after exiting the while loop

Tags: c++

just curious on how to fix this minor issue for cin.

```
int main(){

    int x,w;
    while(cin>>x){
         cout<<"This is x -> " << x << endl;
    }

    //now this cin will not be executed

    cin>> w;

    cout<< "This is w -> "<< w << endl;

    //prints some garbage value for w

}
```

the last cin is being skipped, and prints some garbage value for w, im certain its the way the cin function works, but im not entirely too sure on how to fix the error. I tried cin.clear(), and cin.ignore(), but im unsure of what parameters to put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit from the `while` by entering an incorrect data type (non-numeric input), you need to remove the invalid input from the stream. You can do it like this:

```
while(cin >> x){
    cout << "This is x -> " << x << endl;
}

std::cin.clear();
std::string str;
// read the invalid input from stream in some string 'str'
std::getline(std::cin, a);

// now you can take input normally
std::cin >> w;
```

You need to `#include <string>` for above as well.

Comment: Thank you! seems to work. However, when I run "echo {1..10} | ./filename", the garbage value returns.

Answer (score 0):

You get garbage value when the `While` loop terminates because you have to clear the invalid input stream and then read the standard input before taking another value from the user. I have done something for you. I think it might help you

```
int main() 
   {
    int x, w;
    while (cin >> x)
    {
        cout << "This is x -> " << x << endl;
    }

    cin.clear();  //removing the invalid input from the stream
    getchar();    //reads from standard input
    cout << "Enter w : " << ' ';
    cin >> w;
    cout << "This is w -> " << w << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
5
This is x -> 5
4
This is x -> 4
3
This is x -> 3
t

Enter w :  10
This is w -> 10
```